# netplan will not recognise nameserver on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, server, dns, netplan

What is the point of nameservers in netplan if it is simply ignored and replaced by a file, that is not allowed to be edited by hand?

Here is my configuration, this is a default install, I have never set dns to 127.0.0.1 so that setting is somehow the best idea somebody cam up with...smh.

Can somebody tell me why the nameservers setting in netplan is ignored?

```
ubuntu@raspi01:~$ cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.1.231/24
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            gateway4: 192.168.1.254
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.1.201]
                search: []



ubuntu@raspi01:~$ cat /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg
network: {config: disabled}



ubuntu@raspi01:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.1
search ******************


ubuntu@raspi01:~$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 127.0.0.1
         DNS Servers: 127.0.0.1
          DNS Domain: ************************
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 3 (wlan0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: I resinstalled from scratch for the fifth time and this time, somehow, resolvconf is not installed.

I'm over this. It is the last Ubuntu machine I install.

Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I do not know where to define Current DNS Server. However, I consider this article will be helpful: https://www.ricmedia.com/set-custom-dns-servers-on-ubuntu-18-or-20/. Basically, Ubuntu 20.04 is using Netplan. It appears that resolv.conf is not used by Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: It happened to me with 18.04 Server. It worked fine after I give 2 DNS Server as: nameservers:
              addresses: [192.168.0.1,8.8.8.8]